# Wordpress RSS File Template

Tags: rss

I need to add some code to my RSS feeds, so I am searching for the RSS Feed .php file so I can add my code. Any help in finding this template file would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Feed templates are in `wp-includes` folder, files starting with `feed-`. As rest of the WordPress core they are not supposed to be modified.

You will need to:

1. Determine type of feed you want to modify (usually default RSS 2.0 one).
2. Unhook native function that loads feed template, for example `remove_action('do_feed_rss2','do_feed_rss2');`
3. Create your own feed template.
4. Create and hook your own function that will load your template, by analogue with [`do_feed_rss2()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_feed_rss2) ( [source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.4/wp-includes/functions.php#L1742) ).

Alternatively you can use some specific hooks in feed template to add what you want.

**Update**

As per Otto's comment steps 2 and 4 can be simplified using `add_feed()` function ( [source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.4/wp-includes/rewrite.php#L62) ).

Comment: A fine answer, but I'd recommend using the add_feed function instead. You can use it to replace a feed as well as add new ones.

Comment: @Otto thanks for hint, looked at source and that would be much less cluttered to use indeed

Comment: let's say I edit the feed-rss2.php to change some feature in the presented content. How to apply the configurations? I am not seeing any change in the output

Answer (score 2):

To add some tags to the rss2 feed you may use the 3 action hooks that can be found in the wp-includes/feed-rss2.php

rss2_ns : to add a specific namespace

rss2_head : to add tags in the feed header

rss2_item : to add tags in each feed items

For example, let's assume you want to add a copyright in your feed's header using the dublin core vocabulary :

```
function my_rss2_head(){
    echo '<dc:rights>&copy; '.bloginfo_rss('name').'</dc:rights>'.PHP_EOL;
}
add_action( 'rss2_head', 'my_rss2_head');
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a quick guide: http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Feeds

Comment: Some of the stuff in that article is verrrry old (as per warnings). I'd not rely on it without double checking with other materials and/or source code.